# Given a regression model with heteroscedasticity, find generalized least squares estimator?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, generalized-least-squares

I have $Y_i=\beta_0+U_i, E(U_i)=0, var(U_i)=2log|Z_i|, cov(U_i;U_j)=0$ when $i\neq j$. Suppose there are $n$ observations on $Y_i$ and $Z_i$.

How do I use this information to find the GLS estimator and how to find the variance of this estimator?

Comment: When $-1<Z_i<1$, $var(U_i)<0$?

Comment: What more can you say about $Z_i$?

Answer (score 1):

With $V$ the variance-covariance matrix of the errors, GLS is

$$(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}y$$

In your case, $X=\textbf{1}$, a vector of ones. Due to lack of covariance of the errors, $V^{-1}$ will be diagonal. I denote the elements of $V^{-1}$ by $\sigma^{-2}_i, i=1,\ldots,n$. Then, $X'V^{-1}X=\sum_i\sigma^{-2}_i$ and $X'V^{-1}y=\sum_iy_i/\sigma^{2}_i$.